# limit draggable events on Background event

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have 3 draggable events and I want to be able to only drop 2 of them where the background event has only 2 empty slots. Third one should be rejected. How can I achieve this?

Eempty slots:
[image]

Also i got background events from SQL like this.

```js
 $(function() {
    function ini_events(ele) {
      ele.each(function() {
        var eventObject = {
          title: $.trim($(this).text()),
          color: $(this).data('color')
        }
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject)
        $(this).draggable({
          zIndex: 1070,
          revert: true,
          revertDuration: 0,
        })
      })
    }
    var a;
    ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'))

    $('#btnsave').on('click', function() {

    })
    var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var Draggable = FullCalendar.Draggable;
   <?php if (is_null($id)) { 
    } else {
      foreach ($adaylist[$id] as $a) { ?>
        var containerEl<?= $a['id'] ?> = document.getElementById('draggable<?= $a['id'] ?>');
        //var checkbox = document.getElementById('drop-remove');
        <?php
        $preaid = 0;
        if ($count == 0) {
          foreach ($veri as $v) {
            $hour = (intdiv($v['duration'], 60) . ':' . (($v['duration'] % 60) < 10 ? '0' . ($v['duration'] % 60) : ($v['duration'] % 60)));
            if ($preaid == $v['AssesmentId']) {
              continue;
            } else {
        ?>
              new Draggable(containerEl<?= $a['id'] ?>, {
                itemSelector: '.external-event',
                eventData: function(eventEl) {
                  return {
                    title: eventEl.innerText,
                    duration: '<?= $hour ?>',
                    backgroundColor: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl, null).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
                    borderColor: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl, null).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
                    textColor: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl, null).getPropertyValue('color'),
                    constraint: '<?= $v['AssesmentId'] ?>',
                  };
                }

              })
    <?php }
            $preaid = $v['AssesmentId'];
          }
        }
      }
    } ?>

    var counter = 2;
    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      locale: 'tr',
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      firstDay: '1',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      selectable: true,
      editable: true,
      droppable: true,
      slotDuration: '00:15:00',
      slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
      slotMaxTime: '20:00:00',
      navLinks: true,
      drop: function(info) {
        info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);
      },
events: [
        <?php
        foreach ($veri as $v) {
          $adaycount = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `adaycalendar` INNER JOIN assessdetails ON assessdetails.AssesmentId = adaycalendar.AssesmentId INNER JOIN assessdetailshours ON assessdetailshours.detailid = assessdetails.id WHERE adaycalendar.startDate = '" . $v['startDate'] . "' AND adaycalendar.startTime = '" . $v['startHour'] . "' AND assessdetailshours.endHour = '" . $v['endHour'] . "'")->fetchColumn();
          if ($adaycount == $v['count']) {
            continue;
          } else {
            $v['count'] -= $adaycount;
        ?> {
              groupId: '<?= $v['AssesmentId'] ?>',
              title: '<?= $v['count'] ?> empty slot',
              start: '<?= $v['startDate'] ?>T<?= $v['startHour'] ?>',
              end: '<?= $v['endDate'] ?>T<?= $v['endHour'] ?>',
              display: 'background',
              color: 'green',
            },
        <?php
          }
        }
        ?>
        <?php
```

v[count] is the limiter for background events. I tried to background events title and update it but I could not achieve this with eventReceive. I defined counter after draggable events code. For now just assign constant variable like 2.

```
eventChange:function(changeInfo){
        console.log(changeInfo);
      },
eventReceive: function(info, dropInfo) {
        var events = calendar.getEvents();
        console.log(info.event.start);
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          if (events[i].display == 'background') {
            if (info.event.start.getDate() == events[i].start.getDate()) {
              eventChange(events[i].title);
            }
          }
        }
        counter--;
        if (counter == 0) {
          eventAllow(dropInfo)
        }
      },
  eventAllow: function(dropInfo) {
        if (counter > 0)
          return true;
      },
```

But it gave me an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: eventChange is not defined

Comment: You weren't specific but I assume the error is from this line: `eventChange(events[i].title);` ? The obvious question is, where have you defined a function called `eventChange`? It's not shown in your question. Does it exist? Is it in scope? The error suggests not. Your post starts with a very broad question but then ends with a very specific, common and easy-to-google error message.

Comment: (P.S. I can see that's not the exact error message you received... for clarity, you should always paste the actual error message, and point us to the line which caused it. Don't shorten, paraphrase or otherwise alter the message when posting - it can sometimes make it ambiguous. Thanks.)

Comment: `eventChange(events[i].title);` There is an error line. But first of all, this section which start with eventchange function is my approach to solve my question. I want to restrict background events how many draggable events can drop? Can i achieve with eventReceive function? Thanks for replying.

Comment: what I want to know is if I can restrict the number of events in a background event with this method. If not, what do you suggest?

Comment: In theory anything is possible if you write the correct code for it. There's no particular reason you couldn't do that if you wish. So if you just want to ask about something as broad as that, why did you talk about a specific error message?

Comment: U're right. I just want to show what i'm trying to do and gave me an error like this. And I wonder is there a chance easy way to do it

Comment: Well I think you're on the right track to a solution, but the problem is you haven't got a function called `eventChange`, and I don't know what you want it to do either. So I can't give you any specific help other than to say "you need to define a function called eventChange". That will make the error message go away.